# javascript setTimeout not doing what I expect

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function myfunction()
  {
  window.setTimeout(alert('I waited for you.'),700000000);
  }
```

I call a function like this and I get an immediate alert saying "I waited for you".

I initially put in 7000 as the second argument, but kept pushing it up in case it was something besides seconds. I obviously want the function to do something else, but I broke it down to this simplistic example to prove to myself where the problem lies.

What's my mistake?

Comment: I didn't REALLY want my function to wait 700000000 seconds. That was just a crazy example. If you're using this code for something, reduce that to your actual use-case number of seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a function reference, not the result of executing `alert()` like this:

```
function myfunction() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {alert('I waited for you.')},700000000);
}
```

When you pass `alert('I waited for you.')` to `setTimeout()`, you're telling the javascript interpreter to execute `alert('I waited for you.')` and then pass the return result to `setTimeout()`.  Since that immediately executes the `alert()` statement and alert doesn't return a function for `setTimeout()` to use, that is clearly not what you want.

Instead, you want to pass a function reference to `setTimeout()`.  That can be done either with an anonymous function as in the example I provided above or it can be done with a separate named function like this:

```
function myAlert() {
    alert('I waited for you.');
}

function myfunction() {
    window.setTimeout(myAlert, 700000000);
}
```

Note: for more advanced usages, you can actually pass an immediately executed function to `setTimeout()` as long as that function returns a function reference that `setTimeout()` can call later.  But, that is clearly not the usage you are attempting here with your `alert()`

Comment: Although you can return the result of a function call, that result needs to be a function reference (which `alert()` won't give you) :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function myfunction() {
  window.setTimeout( function(){alert('I waited for you.');}, 700000000);
}
```

In your code the function alert is called immediately. If you want to have a later execution you should pass a reference to a function and not a call of a function to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
function makeAlert(){
  alert('I waited for you.')
}

window.setTimeout(makeAlert,700000000);
```

otherwise the alert() is executed immediatly

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in an anonymous function like:

```
function myfunction(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){alert('I waited for you.')},700000000);
}
```

Here's an **[example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cus5Z/)** (with a more manageable 3 second delay).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply wrap the `alert('I waited for you.')` in quotes `"` as such:

```
function myfunction() 
  { 
  window.setTimeout("alert('I waited for you.')",7000); 
  }
```

The number is the amount of milliseconds to wait, so 7000 is 7 seconds.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Ac5Xf/

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.

Comment: eval is not evil as long as you KNOW what's being evaluated. Since it's not a variable but an actual sting expression, what's the harm?

Answer (score -2):

I found out that if I put quotes around the first argument, it works. Here's what I actually did:

```
function divhide()
  {
  window.setTimeout("realhide()",7000);
  }

function realhide(){
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  mydiv.style.display="none";
  mydiv.innerHTML="";
}
```

Comment: Eeeeck!  Don't put quotes around the argument.  That forces the javascript interpreter to use eval() to re-evaluate the code from string form which is step backwards in many ways.  In your example, you should just use `window.setTimeout(realhide,7000);`

Comment: Why is everyone dead set against eval()? It's part of the language for a reason. I know not to allow a variable to be evaled, so a friendly "Be careful of this method though, because it uses eval" would suffice.

Comment: I'm not dead set against `eval()` when it's appropriate and the best way of getting the job done, but it's just dumb to use it here and a bad practice to teach people because it's entirely unnecessary.  If you wanted to call `document.getElementById('test')`, wouldn't you think it was dumb to do `eval("document.getElementById('test')")` rather than just calling `document.getElementById('test')` directly.  Same thing here - completely unnecessary.